# MooTools: uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript

So, I have this function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    var togglers = $$('div.toggler');
    if(togglers.length) var gmail = new Fx.Accordion(togglers,$$('div.body'));
    togglers.addEvent('click',function() { this.addClass('read').removeClass('unread'); });
    togglers[0].fireEvent('click'); //first one starts out read
});

</script>
```

and I have this error in Inspect element -> console:

```
uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I included this library -> `<script src="mootools-core-1.4.5.js"></script>`

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Try `$$(togglers[0]).fireEvent('click');`

Comment: Where is `Fx.Accordion` ?

Comment: @PSL what do you mean by "where is ..."?

Comment: @user3175636 You should debug and check if FX has Accordion, it must be part of More builder not core. Check http://mootools.net/more125

Comment: @PSL now I got this:

Uncaught ReferenceError: MooTools is not defined mootools-more-1.4.0.1.js:33
(anonymous function)

Comment: @user3175636 You must include it after including the core.

Comment: @PSL my bad. thanks. now I got other problems. meh, I'm going to sleep :d.

Comment: Yes, but I have another problem now. Working on it :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the More library also. You just added Core. Add the More library after the Core code.

```
window.addEvent('domready',function() {
    var togglers = $$('div.toggler');
    if(togglers.length) var gmail = new Fx.Accordion(togglers, $$('div.body'));
    togglers.addEvent('click',function() { this.addClass('read').removeClass('unread'); });
    togglers[0].fireEvent('click'); //first one starts out read
});
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/y45yU/) based on your code.